# CALayer subclass "drawInContext" called but not drawing?

Tags: ios, calayer, quartz-2d

I am trying to draw in a CALayer subclass.
The   `drawInContext`  is called with `setNeedsDisplay` but nothing is drawn.
What am doing/getting wrong here ?

```
 - (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)] fill];

    [@"Vowel" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkboard" size:14]];
}
```

**Edit**
I am getting this error :

> CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0

Thanks
Shani

Comment: i think it helpful http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/57/topics/3577

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're mixing CG calls and UIKit calls. `-[UIBezierPath fill]` and `-[NSString drawAtPoint:withFont:]` both draw into the context at the top of the UIKit context stack. That's not the same thing as the context passed into `-drawInContext:`. You should modify your function to look like:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)] fill];
    [@"Vowel" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkboard" size:14]];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer and should be accepted. I ran into the same issue as the submitter, and wrapping the code between UIGraphicsPushContext/UIGraphicsPopContext calls, as suggested, fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me, took a lot of time to find the right way of doing it